# Rails unable to autoload constant user_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im buliding an app with users model which can have different privileges, described by user_types model (id and type as a string). As I am running rails test, I am getting error

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant User_type, expected app/models/user_type.rb to define it
```

Here is my model:

```
class UserType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :type, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
end
```

Below is the controller and test file

```
class UserTypeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @user_type = User_type.all
    end 
    def new
        @user_type = User_type.build(user_type_params)
    end
    private
    def user_type_params
        params.require(:user_type).permit(:type)
    end
end
```

Testing model:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTypeTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end
  def setup
    @user_type = User_type.new(id:2,type:"test")
  end
  test "is_valid" do
    assert @user_type.valid?
  end

end
```

I wanted to do some basic "is_valid" test and I got an error described above. I have also dropped last model "user_type" and created it as "UserType" but It didn't work.

Comment: do your UserType model located in app/models/user_type.rb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throughout your controller and test you use `User_type.all`, `User_type.build`, `User_type.new`, but your model is named `UserType`.

Answer (score 0):

Your model's class name is `UserType`. `User_type` is not defined anywhere. You either keep the model name as is and fix your test and controller, or rename the model name. The former is the Rails convention, so I'd suggest you go with that (the CamelCased name).

Comment: Allright, but: 
1) That was User_type model name, I have just changed it while ago
2) I get this error after using @UserType=UserType.new: 
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: Invalid single-table inheritance type: test is not a subclass of UserType

Comment: `type` is the default attribute name, if you want to implement Single-table inheritance. You can either rename your column and attribute accessor to something else (e.g. `kind`), or you can change the inheritance column. See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-inheritance_column

Answer (score 0):

Change your model name to `UserType` as defined in class and from that `UserType` model's table remove `type` column or rename it to something like `user_type` since that is a reserved column name, can be used for single table inheritance only.

Comment: I got this: NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for #<UserType:0x00561ec2341fc0>
    test/models/user_type_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UserTypeTest>' my user_type test :   def setup
 @UserType = UserType.new(id:2,description:"test")
  end
  test "check" do
 assert @UserType.valid? 
  end

Comment: Did you renamed the `type` column properly using migration ? and removed  the usage of `type` from everywhere , including in `UserType` controller(in user_type_params)  and  model(i.e in presence validation ) ?